# Limitations and differences of HTML in an email vs a web page

Tags: html, email, html-email

What are the limitations of html in an email?

Beyond the fact that for security reason no Javascript is allowed
and that Css is inline only

What other considerations are required? 
How is responsiveness being handled or the diversity between email clients?

Any does and don'ts rules of thumb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some limitations:

- width should be 600px
- background image is not allowed
- use inline CSS
- try to use `table`-layout

Here are some links for best practices:

- https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/rules-best-practice-email-design-coding-practices/

Comment: isn't the usage of div is preferable over a table?

Comment: You can use div's also but to ensure that your layout renders correctly across all inboxes(mailers). please go through the link https://www.sitepoint.com/rules-best-practice-email-design-coding-practices/

Answer (score 3):

Here are some links to start with:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css - *very comprehensive list*
- https://css-tricks.com/html-email-accessibility
- https://mailchimp.com/help/limitations-of-html-email

Please note:

You may want to research your recipients' email consuming behavior (most popular clients) and target email clients carefully.